# ASP.NET 4.0 C# HTTP Request Error - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I got the error mentioned in the title in ASP.NET 3.5 while running on localhost and I migrated my program to 4.0 to test if it fixes the error. It turns out that it does work in localhost running 4.0 but when I run it on the server, it still gives the error.

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

The code is shown below. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Is there a web config or IIS change that could possibly fix this?

```
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.baseUrl + "/api_users");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    //httpWebRequestProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;


    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        if (this.debug == true)
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            this.emailBody += "User POST Request Successful: " + result + "<br /><br />";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` to an explicit value before your streamWriter using

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Any luck with this? Same issue.